# execute permissions in linux

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I was wondering about why the execute permission is set the way it is in linux.  The execute permissions are permission flags, but they also (for regular files) change how the OS views the file.

So I was wondering, what is the purpose of even having a concept of "executable versus non-executable" regular files?  In other words, what if you made all regular files to be seen by the OS as executable commands, and just made execute permissions behave like permissions?

It would seem that the only difference between this and how things are now is that the super user would be able to execute any file without the need to change the permissions first. Is this the reason?

Or, to rephrase the question: Is the super user's inability to execute a non-executable file without first changing the permissions an intentional design (similar to how read-only mounts and immutable/append-only attributes are designed to prevent the super user from editing without first changing them)?

Or is this just an unintended side-effect of how the system was built?

It would seem to make sense, for safety reasons, to prevent root from accidentally executing.

Comment: What is the purpose of having a concept of "edible versus non-edible" *stuff*? Because, without it, you would eat your silverware, given permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the super user's inability to execute a non-executable file without
>   first changing the permissions an intentional design (similar to how
>   read-only mounts and immutable/append-only attributes are designed to
>   prevent the super user from editing without first changing them)?

It's an intentional design. But not to prevent the root user from something, instead, it's to save the root user from something: from executing files that are not meant to be executed. On UNIX, you may execute anything if the permissions are set. If the file is in an executable binary format known by the system, it gets executed as a binary, if the file contains a [shebang (`#!`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line as the first line, it gets executed as a script by the program listed in that line, if neither of these applies, it gets executed as a script by `/bin/sh`. If the file was not meant to be executed, well, then `/bin/sh` will complain a lot about that junk found in the file... Now, permissions are there to save root user from this.

Comment: The handling of a file that has executable permission, but is not in an executable binary format known by the system and does not begin with a shebang, is dependent on *what shell you try to run it from*. See [Shell script working fine without shebang line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12296308/3960947) and other posts -- some shells use `/bin/sh` and some shells use *themselves* (e.g., `csh` may use `/bin/csh`).

Answer (score 0):

> In other words, what if you made all regular files to be seen by the OS as executable commands, and just made execute permissions behave like permissions?

Well I don't think the OS views the file as an executable or not. It's more like the file has the permission to be executed or not. Now as to why the root user actually depends on the permission to be present somewhere to be executed (if it's the root user he should have all permissions), might be something related to the shell. It could also be that it's not necessary to have all files being treated as executable files. I suppose you would still be making system calls (when you shouldn't) even though they might not do anything.